# Device not ready gradle sync failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, synchronization, build.gradle

Im new to android studio, I imported a project from my PC when I start sync It gives following error
Please help me Iam stuck.

```
Error(17,0) The device is not ready.
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeTjw.png)

Comment: [-.-]how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:

```
1.File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2.Shutdown Android Studio
3.Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
4.Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs
5.Gradle build success
6.Rebuild your project
```

Even After following above steps, your project won't work then I think there is drivers problem so,try to install drivers manually from [this site](http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/).

Answer (score 0):

You are moved **project** from one **machine** to another with a different drive letter and signing config couldn't find the keystore.Comment your **drive letter** and **signing** config **syn** again your **project**.